# How can you inherit category permissions when creating a new channel in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to create a new channel that introduces new permissions (giving specific users specified in the command access) as well as inherit all of the permissions for that category in discord.js.

```js
try {
            let specificOverwrites = [
                ...members,
                {
                    id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel]
                }
            ];

            const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create({
                name: allianceNameInput,
                type: ChannelType.GuildText,
                parent: alliancesCategory.id,
                permissionOverwrites: specificOverwrites
            });

            await channel.lockPermissions();

            const roleMentions = members.map(member => `<@&${member.id}>`).join(' ');

            channel.send(`Successfully created alliance. ${roleMentions}`);
            console.log(roleMentions);
            const newAlliance = new Alliance(allianceNameInput, players, channel.id, tribe);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(players, null, 2));
            controller.addAlliance(newAlliance);
            await interaction.reply(`Created alliance channel: ${channel}`);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Could not create alliance channel.', error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'Could not create alliance channel.', ephemeral: true });
        }
```

I've been told that .lockPermissions(); will sync the channel with the inherited commands, but that isn't working. I can't get a straight answer as to how to do this.

I ran the above command and it creates the channel but does not sync with channel permissions unlike if i create it normally through discord.